# predict function nnet in R

Tags: r

```
nnet_f1 <- 
nnet(Z24train$f1~Z24train$TSU+Z24train$TSL+Z24train$TW+Z24train$TP,size=10,linout=T)
plot(Z24$datahora,Z24$f1,col=1,xlab="time", ylab ="f(Hz)",pch="x")
legend("topright","1stMode",text.col=1,bty="n")
lines(Z24train$datahora[complete.cases(Z24train$datahora)],nnet_f1$fitted.values,col="blue",pch="x") 
predict <- predict(nnet_f1, newdata = Z24test)

> predict <- predict(nnet_f1, newdata = Z24test)
Error in predict.nnet(nnet_f1, newdata = Z24test) : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 282 rows but variables found have 3315 rows

I have problem with the function predict. Can you help me?
My data are diveded in two groups, train and test. Now i want to find the function predict for the data test. Thank you

Comment: Does the test set have the same column names as the training set? Instead of `df$col1~df$col2+...` try `col1~col2+..., data=df`

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? It'll be easier to help you then

Comment: You mean with the first suggestion I gave?

Comment: Glad to hear! No problem :)